# pandas dataframe get a column total and print the "TOTAL" in previous column in same line

Tags: python, dataframe, z-index

I want to move the value in 0th column in a data frame to a different column

I get the total of the column `Amount_AUD` in my data frame as `Total_AUD` from below code.

```
df.loc['Total_AUD'] = pd.Series(df['Amount_AUD'].sum(), index=['Amount_AUD'])
```

I have noticed that `Total_AUD` coming up in 0th column. But I need it in the previous column where I print the total of the `Amount_AUD`.

| City | Amount_AUD |
| --- | --- |
| City 1 | 200.00 |
| City 3 | 100.00 |
| Total_AUD | 300.00 |

Can someone give me direction please

Comment: Please start solving the iproblem, and then ask for help